# Unsafe usage of [unsafe]

Tags: discussion, questions, tag-wiki

This is an excerpt of the [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe) tag wiki :

> In C# or Rust, the unsafe keyword marks code able to work directly with memory pointers, bypassing some of the language's safety checks.

However, I noticed that this tag is also used for questions related to the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class of Java (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32045459/1743880) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31339045/1743880) one).

As it currently stands, there are:

- [324 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+unsafe) tagged [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe) and [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23);
- [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe+rust) tagged [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe) and [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust);
- [44 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe+java) tagged [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Should the tag wiki be edited to mention this Java class or should we create another tag for this?

I am not familiar with C# or Rust but, although `unsafe` is not a keywork in Java, it also permits low-level operations, bypassing completely the language's safety checks.

Comment: It's another meta tag that relies on other tags to provide context. Imo, it should be burninated, possibly replaced with tags like `c#-unsafe`, `rust-unsafe` and `java-unsafe`

Comment: In other words... this tag is [unsafe]. @Cerbrus

Comment: I like @Cerbrus's comment but I think the tags should be `unsafe-c#`, `unsafe-rust`, and `unsafe-java` since users will be more likely to see them when they start typing the class name.

Comment: @SteveTauber: `c#-unsafe` will be shown as hint when you start typing _"unsafe"_. It's a "contains" filter.

Comment: I fixed your borken query.  What you do with it is entirely up to you.  And no, as the SO user with the most answers in the [unsafe] tag, I can attest that this has never been a real problem.  This doesn't need to be fixed.

Comment: @BoltClock http://i.stack.imgur.com/7WlKy.png